# Sometimes curl_multi_exec repeat requests

Tags: php, curl

I'm doing some requests with curl_multi_exec. My code looks like this:

```
$rMultiHandler = curl_multi_init();

//next lines are repeated for several resources
$rResource = curl_init();       
curl_setopt($rResource, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($rResource, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($rResource, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($rResource, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1800);
curl_setopt($rResource, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_multi_add_handle($rMultiHandler, $rResource);
//-----------------------

$iRunningProcesses = null;
do {
    curl_multi_exec($rMultiHandler, $iRunningProcesses);
    usleep(100000);
} while ($iRunningProcesses > 0);

//do some work with received data;

curl_multi_close($rMultiHandler);
```

The problem is that these requests are time consuming (5-10 minutes). And sometimes one of these requests (the longest) is repeated twice. It seems like curl wait awhile for data, doesn't receive anything and repeats the request.
How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the wrong configuration Apache and fсgi. After increasing the timeouts problem went away (`timeout` for apache, `FcgidIOTimeout` and `FcgidBusyTimeout` for fcgi).